# regular expression to exclude dash and underscore as last character

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression to validate the below conditions,

```
1) include - (dash)  and _ (underscore) as valid components. 
2) cannot end with (dash) and (underscore).
```

Im using this - `^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-_]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$` but not sure how to include the second condition ie-Cannot end with dash or underscore

Comment: Does a string ending with dash/underscore match your regex? If it doesn't when you test it, then your regex is already doing that!

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
^.*[^-_]$
```

This allows any sequence of characters from the beginning (`^.*`), ending (`$`) with any character that is not a dash or underscore (`[^-_]`). If your valid non-ending characters are only alphanums plus `-_`, then instead of `.*`, use `[A-Za-z0-9-_]*`.

Comment: Changing to `^.+[^-_]$` will even avoid matching empty strings.

Comment: @JasonAller Using `^.*[^-_]$` already prevents matching an empty string since `[^-_]` will match at least one character.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

```
^[^-_].*[^-_]$
```

it may not start with `-` or `_` = `^[^-_]` and it may not end with `-` or `_` = `[^-_]$`

Comment: It only asks for end, not start. Aside from that, I'd vote up.