# Regex not start with dot or end with dot

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression that does not start with a dot or end with `[-_.]`.

This regex works but fails for the first condition; it does not start with dot:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][^.]*[^-_.][A-Za-z0-9]$
```

For example: `test.com` should be a valid string but it fails.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21557658/1578604), you should be able to use:

```
^[^.].*[^-_.]$
```

But if you want to be able to match a 1 character string, you will need negative lookaheads:

```
^(?![.])(?!.*[-_.]$).+
```

And if you want to match empty strings too, simply use `*` instead of `+`.

```
^(?![.])(?!.*[-_.]$).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookaheads to assert your requirements for the string:

```
^(?!^\.)(?!.*[-_.]$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

- First character not a "."
- Last character not a "-", "_", or "."
- Also at least one character in length

Comment: Inbetween the first character and last character it should be only numbers or characters

Comment: ^[^.][A-Za-z0-9]*[^-_.]$ --this one works..does it look good?

Comment: If you *always* have at least two characters, yes.