# What regex pattern will support windows folder creation?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the regular expression for windows folder creation. For instance, it should reject strings that start and end with a dot (`.`), and restrict some special characters (`\/:*?"<>|`)

I often visit [Regex not start with dot or end with dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558681/regex-not-start-with-dot-or-end-with-dot?rq=1)

Can someone provide this?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression should be able to identify invalid characters (based on your example): `/^\.|\.$|[\\\/:*?"<>|]/`.

- `^\.` - starts with `.`
- `\.$` - ends with `.`
- `[\\\/:*?"<>|]` - any of the following invalid characters (note that some of them had to be escaped with `\`)
- `|` - works like an *or* between the different expressions

Example:

```js
function isValidFile(filename) {
  const invalidExp = /^\.|\.$|[\\\/:*?"<>|]/;
  return !invalidExp.test(filename);
}

console.log(isValidFile('file.name'));
console.log(isValidFile('.invalidfile.name'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile.name.'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile?name'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile>name'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile*name'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile:name'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile/name'));
console.log(isValidFile('invalidfile\\name'));
```

Comment: Its not meet my expectatins and I need validation for folder same as windows folder creations

Comment: Can you provide samples of what should be valid versus invalid?